# Ubuntu server RAID-5 failed, rebuilding fails

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, mdadm, raid-5

My Ubuntu server now fails to boot: It uses a RAID 5, and one of those drives failed.  The OS is on the RAID array, and rebuilding now fails with the replacement drive.

I can't post pastebins or anything because I only have physical access using a live drive at the moment.

Using [mdadm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mdadm.8.html) I see drive /dev/sde failed completely (won't show up on the system at all). Using mdadm - - examine I found out that the other drives still know that they belong to a RAID-5. And under array state I see drive three out of the six is missing (AA.AAA).

However, if I try to assemble it, it only wants to use drive three, which isn't enough to build the RAID-5 back up; even more, it wants to make it RAID-0.

How do I fix this?

Edit: this would be on ubuntu 18.04.3 live cd, running from usb

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Please click [edit] and add it to your original question.

Comment: It is not clear which drives have failed and which drives you have replaced. Please be more specific. **NOTE: If you have lost 2 drives in a RAID5 then all of your data is lost. Format and start over.**

Comment: Plz post your `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` here

Comment: We definitively need more info to understand your raid config and which disks are seen in the machine. So some `cat /proc/mdstat`, `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`, `ls -l /dev/sd?`, `fdisk -l /dev/sd?` will help to confirm that the 3rd disk in the array is actually /dev/sde.

Comment: I will try to do that! As soon as i get home this evening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with the `--run` flag:

> Once  an  appropriate array is found or created and the device is
>   added, mdadm must decide if the array is ready to be started.  It will
>   normally compare  the  number  of  available (non-spare) devices to
>   the number of devices that the metadata suggests need to be active. If
>   there are at least that many, the array will  be  started.   This 
>   means  that  if  any devices are missing the array will not be
>   restarted.
>
> As  an  alternative,  **--run  may be passed to mdadm in which case the
>   array will be run as soon as there are enough devices present for the
>   data to be accessible**.  For a RAID1, that means  one  device  will
>   start the array.  **For a clean RAID5, the array will be started as soon
>   as all but one drive is present.**

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mdadm.8.html

Comment: Thank you! Rl has gotten in the way, i will try it soon and report back!